# Plotting nodes and links from JSON files with SVG

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I'm new to D3 and I'm having trouble visualising my json file. I'm supposed to plot the locations (sites) as circles with their radius equal to the "amount". I'm extremely confused about how to work with the nodes and links. I have provided an example of the JSON code as well. Please help me understand where I am going wrong with the coding

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>D3 Visualisation </title>
<h1> Trading Data </h1>
 <style>
.svgCanvas {
border: solid 1px
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> <script>
window.onload = function(){ 
    var width = 800;
    var height = 300;
    var thisCanvas = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "svgCanvas");


d3.json("data.json", function(d){
    console.log(d);

var svgCanvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.amount; } )
    .style("fill", “lightgreen”); }) 


})
    }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Json code example is as follows:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "site09",
      "x": 317.5,
      "y": 282.5
    },
    {
      "id": "site01",
      "x": 112,
      "y": 47
    },
    {
      "id": "site03",
      "x": 69.5,
      "y": 287
    }
  ],

  "links": [
    {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site08", "amount": 10},
    {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site02", "amount": 120},
    {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site03", "amount": 50}
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you please share what you have tried till now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you can get the working solution. Just replace the data object with json.

https://playcode.io/324480?tabs=console&script.js&output